# Is it possible to perform a complete reinstall on an Android smartphone?

Tags: installation

I occasionally perform such a reinstall on my Windows PC. I repartition my hard drive, format the partitions, and then install Windows on a blank partition. Can this be done on an Android smartphone? (I have an unlocked Sony Xperia S.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's very possible. Basically you can flash a ROM (custom or stock) very easily, and this is equivalent to a full format and reinstall.

Basic steps would be:

1. Acquire preferred ROM and transfer to SD card / internal memory
2. Reboot into Recovery (Hold Volume Up as you power up the phone)
3. Flash ROM

This is covered more in depth at these links (XDA is a great resource):

[Overall "guides" for the Xperia S](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1526866)

["Guide" to flashing the Xperia S](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=23181205#post23181205) (it's a fairly light-on-detail guide though, it is a very simple process)

Comment: I would add that in most cases, a factory restore from recovery will bring a stock (an non-rooted) Android device back to its original state.  Factory reset wipes out all user data, and since the system partition is read-only and isn't touched during normal operation, that is usually sufficient.  For rooted devices where system partition(s) are modified (and especially if a custom ROM was installed,) the above is the best way to get a device back to its original state.

Comment: Not a problem - just amused me at the time. I should have added a smiley face to indicate that. ;) Best of luck! I generally find the most difficult thing is the key combination to get to recovery, as it changes due to availability of h/w buttons. I'll try and find it and add it to my answer. Also removed the "complaint".

Comment: @Chahk My device came with preinstalled apps (e.g. McAfee, and some T-mobile crapware), and a carrier logo animation on device boot. I'm not sure that those would be cleared with a factory restore. It's for that reason I'm thinking about a complete reinstall. I would like to get rid of all that preinstalled and carrier-specific stuff, and get a clean Android install.

Comment: To do that you'll need to root and install a Custom ROM.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Pre-installed apps most definitely would not be removed with a factory restore, since carriers and manufacturers place them in read-only areas.

Comment: It should be added that a factory reset does *not* touch the `/system` partition (where Android system files are stored). So if you root your device, it stays rooted. If you flash a CustomROM, it would not revert to stock by a factory reset. Just `/data` and caches are "wiped" -- so all app data and user-installed apps plus all configuration is gone after this.

Comment: @Izzy Absolutely correct.  In my comment when I said *"For rooted devices ...  the above is the best way to get a device back to its original state"*, by "the above" I meant jeeva's answer (i.e. ROM flashing)

Comment: Note that the device's warranty may be void after flashing any ROM, even a vanilla stock ROM. Check your warranty details.